# wordpress mysql rds slow after restoring from dump

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-rds

I have hosted wordpress database in AWS RDS in a t3.medium. I took a mysql dump and restored it in db.m6i.large.

```
mysqldump --quick --single-transaction --host myrdsdb.crrwsfsdkmf3g.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --user tk --databases wp-staging --password --no-tablespaces > wp-stg-dump2.sql
```

When I run a very small crawler on the db.m6i.large. CPU goes to 100%. Also RDS performance insites show high `wait/io/file/myisam/dfile`

[image]

The same crawl when I run in the original t3.medium. I do not face this issue. Is here some thing wrong with the way I am taking dump?

Comment: Can you share the queries you are running against the DB? Or at least sharing the EXPLAIN plan would help to identify what could cause the slowdown.

Comment: When check the slow query log for more than 1 sec nothing is registering. Also please note the same db on the original instance does not have this slowness.

Comment: Don't use MyISAM, use InnoDB.

Comment: @kumar Running into an identical issue except on DO Managed Database. Did you ever find the issue here?